# How to create three level object in YAML metadata in Rmd?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I found a great example how to create two-level object in YAML metadata [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block). For example, in order to include more than one author

```
---
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
author:
- name: Author One
  affiliation: University of Somewhere
- name: Author Two
  affiliation: University of Nowhere
---
```

Then in html `template`

```
$for(author)$
$if(author.name)$
$author.name$$if(author.affiliation)$ ($author.affiliation$)$endif$
$else$
$author$
$endif$
$endfor$
```

Is it possible to create three-level object in YAML? For example, I want to have more than one author from the same institution. Therefore, my logic is

```
---
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
author:
  - affiliation: 
     - name: Author One
       email: fake@fake.com
     - name: Author Two
       email: fake2@fake.com
  - affiliation: 
     - name: Author Three
       email: fake3@fake.com
---
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to do it? I know it looks like it does not make any sense, but it's necessary for my html `template` structure.

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE**

I also add a chunk which I created in html `template`.

```
$if(author)$
$for(author)$
<div class = "author-section">
<div>$author.affiliation$</div>
<div class = "authors">
$for(author.affiliation)$
<div class = "author">
<div class = "mid-col">
$author.affiliation.name$
</div>
<div class = "right-col">
<a>$author.affiliation.email$</a>
</div>
</div>
$endfor$
</div>
</div>
$endfor$
$endif$
```

Then, it works fine, except for `$author.affiliation$` which does not have a value in my YAML. Therefore, after rendering, I get "true" string in my final .html file.

However when I add a word for affirmation in YAML, e.g.

```
author:
  - affiliation: University of Somewhere
     - name: Author One
       email: fake@fake.com
```

I get an error during rendering

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 9, column 19
```

Comment: You can nest YAML lists and objects as deep as you want (google YAML). However, you need to modify four HTML template accordingly (add more `$for` loops). I don't get what output you're expecting or what's the goal of your nesting...

Comment: @mb21 Thanks, I edited my question. Please look at it once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would just leave it as it is in your first example. You can write the same affiliation name twice for two different authors.

However, if you really want to write the YAML to group/nest authors by university, it would look something like this (try some online YAML to JSON converter if you're familiar with JSON):

```
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
university:
  - label: University of Somehwere
    author:
     - name: Author One
       email: fake@fake.com
     - name: Author Two
       email: fake2@fake.com
  - label: University of Nohwere
    author:
     - name: Author Three
       email: fake3@fake.com
```

Then the pandoc template loop would look something like this:

```
$for(university)$
<div>
  $university.label$
  $for(university.author)$
    $university.author.name$
    <span class="">$university.author.email$</span>
  $endfor$
</div>
$endfor$
```